# Pytorch forecasting - Assertion Error when trying to forecast with new data with N-BEATS

Tags: python, pandas, pytorch, time-series, pytorch-lightning

After training N-BEATS model, I want to predict with an out of sample dataframe with the length of max_encoder_lentgh as an input, and should have an output of max_prediction_length.

It throws "AssertionError: filters should not remove entries all entries - check encoder/decoder lengths and lags" if the length of the dataframe is lower than: max_encoder_length + max_prediction_length.

This makes impossible to forecast in out-of-sample data.

gist: https://gist.github.com/fornasari12/5ae6dc414f730beb2bd5c8e267b6c9f1
env:

```
pytorch-forecasting==0.9.0
pytorch-lightning==1.5.0
lightning-flash[tabular]>=0.5.2
torch==1.8.1
statsmodels==0.12.1
sktime==0.8.1
scikit-learn==0.24.2
pyarrow==3.0.0
pandas==1.2.5
numpy==1.20.3
matplotlib==3.4.3
PyYAML==6.0
```

```py
import os
import warnings

from config import load_config
from load_data import LoadData

import pandas as pd
import pytorch_lightning as pl
from pytorch_lightning.callbacks import EarlyStopping, LearningRateMonitor
from pytorch_lightning.loggers import TensorBoardLogger
from pytorch_lightning.callbacks import EarlyStopping
import torch

from pytorch_forecasting import Baseline, NBeats, TimeSeriesDataSet
from pytorch_forecasting.data import NaNLabelEncoder
from pytorch_forecasting.data import GroupNormalizer
from pytorch_forecasting.data.examples import generate_ar_data
from pytorch_forecasting.metrics import SMAPE

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    timesteps = 1000

    data = generate_ar_data(seasonality=10.0, timesteps=timesteps, n_series=100, seed=42)
    data["static"] = 2
    data["date"] = pd.Timestamp("2020-01-01") + pd.to_timedelta(data.time_idx, "D")
    
    data.series = data.series.astype(str).astype("category")
    
    max_encoder_length = 30
    max_prediction_length = 15

    cutoff = timesteps * 0.70
    train_data = data[data["time_idx"] <= cutoff]
    test_data = data[data["time_idx"] > cutoff]

    training = TimeSeriesDataSet(
        train_data,
        time_idx="time_idx",
        target="value",
#         categorical_encoders={"series": NaNLabelEncoder().fit(train_data.series)},
        group_ids=["series"],
        time_varying_unknown_reals=["value"],
        max_encoder_length=max_encoder_length,
        max_prediction_length=max_prediction_length,
        # allow_missing_timesteps=True,
    )
    # training_cutoff = train_data["time_idx"].max() - max_prediction_length
    validation = TimeSeriesDataSet.from_dataset(training, train_data, predict=True, stop_randomization=True)
    batch_size = 1024
    train_dataloader = training.to_dataloader(train=True, batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=0)
    val_dataloader = validation.to_dataloader(train=False, batch_size=batch_size * 10, num_workers=0)

    # configure network and trainer
    pl.seed_everything(42)

    early_stop_callback = EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", min_delta=1e-4, patience=10, verbose=False, mode="min")
    trainer = pl.Trainer(
        max_epochs=3,
        gpus=0,
        weights_summary="top",
        gradient_clip_val=0.01,
        callbacks=[early_stop_callback],
        # limit_train_batches=30,
    )

    net = NBeats.from_dataset(
        training,
        learning_rate=0.01,
        log_interval=10,
        log_val_interval=1,
        weight_decay=1e-2,
        widths=[32, 512],
        backcast_loss_ratio=1.0,
    )

    trainer.fit(
        net,
        train_dataloader=train_dataloader,
        val_dataloaders=val_dataloader,
    )

    # THIS PRODUCES:
    # AssertionError: filters should not remove entries all entries - check encoder/decoder lengths and lags
    y_hat_tft = net.predict(
            test_data[test_data["series"] == '0'][:max_encoder_length],
            mode="prediction",
            return_x=True)
```